# How to check whether a variable is a SwigObject type

Tags: python

I want to check whether a variable is a SwigObject type. I am trying to use `isinstance` built-in but doesn't know what need to be passed (i.e. `isinstance(obj, ???)`).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to know only if it is an instance of that particular class, or also if it has it as it as one of the ancestors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply asking for this?

```
>>> a = list()
>>> isinstance(a, int)
False
>>> isinstance(a, list)
True
```

As you can see the first argument of `isinstance` is your object instantiation, the second - in your case - would probably look like `swig.SwigObject` (you need to provide the correct "path" to the class, including its module).

**EDIT:** Motivated by the comment below, I made an additional dump to test and clarify how your class should look like:

```
>>> import numpy as np  #notice that the module's name change here...
>>> a = np.array(())
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>  #...type still returns the full name of the module...
>>> isinstance(a, numpy.ndarray)  #...but if you try to use the full name here...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
>>> isinstance(a, np.ndarray)  #...instead you must use the name known in your namespace
True
```

Comment: doesn't it depend on his import statement on how it will look?

Comment: @GoingTharn - yes, this is why I used the word "probably", but I am not sure though. Let me edit that... :o

Comment: @GoingTharn - done, thank you for the extra motivation in checking! ;)

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't know what is the module name I should import for SwigObject.

Comment: @HailiangZhang - It's your code, not mine... there is no way I can know! :) You could try `swig.SwigObject`, but mine is purely a guess!

Comment: Obviously, OP asks for a *generic* way to test if an object is a swig object (or inherits from a swig object). I don't quite understand how this answers the question, to be honest.